# VSIX: how to pack two or more vspackage into a vsix

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm working on a Visual Studio extension project, providing language service for Lua(this feature is already done). Now I'm going to add a project type for Lua. Now there will be two VsPackage classs(one for lunguage service, one for project type) in the project.
When I'm debugging the project, project type seems not work, which haven't show up a Lua project type when click 'New Project'. When I tested it in an empty project, it works well.
Here is the first package:

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1650:ElementDocumentationMustBeSpelledCorrectly", Justification = "pkgdef, VS and vsixmanifest are valid VS terms")]
[ProvideProjectFactory(typeof(NPLProjectFactory), null,
"NPL Project Files (*.nplproj);*.nplproj", "nplproj", "nplproj",
".\\NullPath", LanguageVsTemplate = "NPL")]
[ProvideProjectItem(typeof(NPLProjectFactory), "NPL Items", ".\\NullPath", 500)]
[Guid(Guids.guidNPLProjectPkgString)]
[ProvideObject(typeof(NPLPropertyPage))]
[ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)]
public sealed class NPLProjectPackage : CommonProjectPackage
{

}
```

second

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
[InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)]

[ProvideKeyBindingTable(GuidList.guidNPLLanguageServiceEditorFactoryString, 102)]
//[ProvideEditorLogicalView(typeof(EditorFactory), "{7651a703-06e5-11d1-8ebd-00a0c90f26ea}")]
[ProvideService(typeof(ILuaLanguageService), ServiceName = "NPL Language Service")]
// Provide the language service for the .lua extension
[ProvideLanguageExtension(typeof(LanguageService), Configuration.Extension)]
[ProvideLanguageService(typeof(LanguageService), Configuration.Name, 110,
    CodeSense = true,
    EnableCommenting = true,
    MatchBraces = true,
    MatchBracesAtCaret = true,
    ShowCompletion = true,
    ShowMatchingBrace = true,
    AutoOutlining = true,
    EnableAsyncCompletion = true,
    QuickInfo = true,
    EnableFormatSelection = true,
    CodeSenseDelay = 1000)]
[ProvideToolWindow(typeof(SourceOutlineToolWindow), Style = VsDockStyle.Tabbed)]

//This attribute is needed to let the shell know that this package exposes some menus.
[ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)]
[ProvideAutoLoad("F1536EF8-92EC-443C-9ED7-FDADF150DA82")] // = VSConstants.UICONTEXT_SolutionExists.ToString()
// there is bug in vs 2015 for associating language service with code expansion
// https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41f559c9-fa86-4108-b516-2d2fabd432a2/code-snippets-not-working-in-vs-2012?forum=vsx
[ProvideLanguageCodeExpansion(typeof(LanguageService), Configuration.Name, 110, Configuration.Name,
        @"%InstallRoot%\NPL\Snippets\%LCID%\SnippetsIndex.xml",
        // the paths of the snippet files
        SearchPaths = @"%InstallRoot%\NPL\Snippets\%LCID%\Lua\;",
        ForceCreateDirs = @"%InstallRoot%\NPL\Snippets\%LCID%\Lua\;")]
[Guid(GuidList.guidNPLLanguageServicePkgString)]
public sealed class NPLLanguageServicePackage : BasePackage
{

}
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance!
Here is my project link:https://github.com/LiXizhi/NPL

Comment: There's no reason you can't do that, but if you can point to a before/after commit in your repo then we can help. I don't know what your repo looks like or what files I should be looking at.

Comment: https://github.com/LiXizhi/NPL/commit/a9feb9b4127834005218606ba40bb767e5ab8652 This is the commit. The new project type added is under VsNPL/NPLLanguageService/Project/ folder.